# Upgraded Angular 7 to 11 after that @hallysonh/ngx-imageviewer next, previous and zoom options are not working

Tags: angular11, image-viewer

I upgrade Angular 7 to 11 after that @hallysonh/ngx-imageviewer@2.0.4 (next, previous and zoom) options are not working. I tried with both node 12.20.0 and 14.15.0.I'm able to view the pdf[these buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIzyd.png) but previous, next, zoom buttons are not working. nothing is happening while clicking it. I guess my pdfjs-dist@2.0.489 is not compatible with Angular 11. May I know the pdfjs-dist suitable version for Angular11?

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.14",
    "@hallysonh/ngx-imageviewer": "^2.0.4",
    "@stomp/stompjs": "^4.0.7",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^4.2.0",
    "@types/highcharts": "^5.0.36",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.29",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "angular-user-idle": "^2.2.1",
    "angular2-tree-diagram": "^1.0.6",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "core-js": "2.5.4",
    "d3": "^5.7.0",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fscreen": "^1.0.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "highcharts": "^7.0.3",
    "highcharts-angular": "^2.4.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.23.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.23",
    "ng-sidebar": "^8.0.0",
    "ng2-ace-editor": "^0.3.9",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^2.0.489",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.5",
    "print-js": "1.0.47",
    "proj4": "^2.5.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.7",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.3.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.18",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.2.18",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~11.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "glob-run": "^0.1.7",
    "husky": "^4.2.5",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "js-beautify": "^1.11.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.16",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "lint-staged": "^10.2.9",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "tslint-sonarts": "^1.9.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.8"
  }
}
```